# Visual studio launch.json file setting will be reverted once i close Visual studio or rerun the program again

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging, vscode-debugger

Im using Visual studio for C program debugging, default configuration of launch.json is added by visual studio in attached image format, with this im getting error so i have edited the cwd,program in the below format

"cwd": "${fileDirname}",

"program": "${fileDirname}\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"

after saving the  cwd,program changes, if i run the code again or re-open Visual studio cwd,program will be changed to default setting.

please let me know how to save the launch.json after editing.

thanks!

[image]

Comment: You can press Ctrl + S to save the file like `launch.json` in VS Code, or click File => Auto save to automatically save the files which you have modified. If you don’t save the files, when you close VS Code, a window should be prompted to ask you if you need to save this file. Did you modify something(configurations)? Is this issue reproducible on a newly created C project? Could you share us the detailed steps to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Hello @Tianyu, I'm saving the launch.json file after modifying and autosave also enabled but still when I edit the launch.json and start the debug it will work. after that if i run the code again the file editing it will be reset and also when visual studio is reopened after saving the launch.json file modification, file is resetting.